# Error MSB4067: The element <ProductVersion> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized

Tags: ssas, azure-pipelines

I am using VS 2017 and i have one SSAS project. I am using VSTS build and release tool to deploy solution. When tried to build the solution I am getting the below error, 
Error MSB4067: The element  beneath element  is unrecognized

How can I resolve this issue, any idea

Comment: Multidimensional or Tabular?

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? You can share a sample project on the OneDrive.